# I have to insert three rows in to sql server at a time

Tags: java, sql-server, multithreading

I have to insert three rows in to sql server from java at a time and i do not want any other  rows between them from other threads . what can I do for that?

Comment: What do you mean you don't want other rows between them? A table by definition has no order. You can do you inserts as a single select statement but honestly the order of insertion shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @SeanLange is correct.  But if what you say really is a requirement, research SQL transactions.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use java.sql.Statement.addBatch(), java.sql.Statement.executeBatch. 
For more details see this [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/)

```
String [] queries = {
    "insert into employee (name, city, phone) values ('A', 'X', '123')",
    "insert into employee (name, city, phone) values ('B', 'Y', '234')",
    "insert into employee (name, city, phone) values ('C', 'Z', '345')",
};
Connection connection = new getConnection();
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

for (String query : queries) {
    statement.addBatch(query);
}
statement.executeBatch();
statement.close();
connection.close();
```

But if you have multiple threads which is inserting in the same table frequently you might need to `synchronized` your inserting method 
For synchronized [details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

Answer (score 0):

How to insert three rows into SQL? just a statement like this!

> insert into table values(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3)

Not wanting other rows between them? I don't think that is necessary to you since three rows to insert takes milliseconds therefore other threads have enough time to add their rows to SQL.

Comment: Kind of questions should be in comments not in answers